# Is there an open source video processing/sensor based follow me technology?

Tags: multirotor, software, long-range-drone, sensor, video

I'm constructing a multirotor drone and want to introduce follow me feature, are there any open source solutions I can use for that purpose?
Please note that I want the tracking algorithm to be autonomous based on some video processing and sensors.

Comment: I do not know about any existing solutions but if you are into coding and (most likely a lot of) tinkering you might want to have a look at OpenCV and its Haar-Cascades. This at least should get you far enough to track people on a video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [dronecode.org](https://www.dronecode.org/), or their supported [projects](https://www.dronecode.org/projects/). Especially, PX4 (which was also mentioned in another answer):

- [Getting Started with PX4 Autopilot guide](https://docs.px4.io/master/en/getting_started/)
- [PX4's Follow-Me Flight Mode](https://docs.px4.io/master/en/flight_modes/follow_me.html)
- [MAVLink's Follow Me plugin](https://mavsdk.mavlink.io/develop/en/guide/follow_me.html)

You may also find some interest in some other [open sourced drone projects](https://opensource.com/article/18/2/drone-projects), e.g. [ArduPilot's Follow Me Mode](https://ardupilot.org/copter/docs/ac2_followme.html). Another one would be [DRONEKIT](http://dronekit.io/)'s [Follow Me Example](https://dronekit-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/follow_me.html).

If you are interested in NVIDIA hardware, take a look at [Redtail - autonomous visual navigation components](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/redtail/wiki).

Answer (score 2):

The **[PX4](https://px4.io/)** open-source flight stack has made some progress on **[various forms of computer vision](https://docs.px4.io/master/en/computer_vision/)**. While not exactly turnkey, it’s an active area of development and you absolutely can buy hardware that supports it as long as you’re comfortable getting your hands dirty setting up the software.

Answer (score 0):

No. Several companies tried, failed, and went bankrupt.

Also NO because there are device specific needs (if not using a fob) such as:

- what is the camera
- onboard processor/FPGA
- FC is important because you need to interface discretely

I am confident it is possible, but where the technology stands right now you will need to roll your own.

Expect to see these operations grow, in the past few years small and affordable LIDAR has become real. Generally we need components and APIs to stabilize so people can effectively write code against a stable system.

Watch the Parallax, Sparkfun, and similar communities generally centered on Arduino development.  I anticipate projects crossing over with those people.